Bash: Reading in a string from a file with variable substitution
I have a weird situation where I have a command stored in a file and that file contains references to variables.
I'm able to read the file just fine, but I'm having trouble getting variable expansion working.
As a minimum working example, here is a file that contains a command with a variable as an example:
command.in
ls $DIR

simple.sh
#!/bin/bash

MYVAR=$(<command.in)
DIR="/tmp"

$MYVAR

Expected Results
My expected results is that it'll print the contents of /tmp
What I've tried
I've tried moving DIR assignment above MYVAR assignment in simple.sh and I've tried changing the $DIR in command.in to ${DIR} and $(DIR)

You'd need to use eval to evaluate the string to ls <content of $DIR> before trying to execute the command. I would recommend not defining command.in like this; just make it a script which takes an argument (ls "$1"), then execute command.in "$DIR".

I think you need eval

@chepner I'm actually doing some weird yocto stuff where I want to call a script after all of the images are generated, but the environment hasn't been torn down yet.
I could have hardcoded the contents of the script into the recipe, but that's a bit of an anti-pattern for if the script needs to change or if I need to share this with another team I'm working with.
I could still do $1 and so on, but for ease of use I have the script parameterized.

Style note: You should not use UPPER CASE for Bash variables. By convention, upper case is reserved for shell use like PATH. User variables should use lower case...

What you are currently doing is even more of anti-pattern. command.in is not currently parmaterized; that's what I'm suggesting you do.

@chepner I mean I really have the contents of the 'real' contents.in parametrized. It's using getopts and everything. To avoid making the question overly specific, I didn't see the benefit of having contents.in being myprog --dir $DIR vs ls $DIR. If you think it'll help future people searching, then I'll happily update it.

The command executed by command.in doesn't matter. The point is that you should execute the script with an argument (command.in "$DIR", which executes myprog --dir "$1" with $1 expanding to the value of $DIR) instead of trying to dynamically expand a hard-coded parameter expansion in the contents of command.in.

@SailorCire You may be right about your specific case. It is not the point of Chepner and I comments. Keep in mind this place is for people with a wide range of coding level. Scholar, modern, verbose or even pedantic code syntax will serve more people than something that cut corners and can potentially infuse bad practice to beginners who don't have the experience and background to know if cutting corners for their specific use case is a valid choice.

$(<command.in) does dereference a variable. You can see what is happening if you put an echo in the script:
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/tmp"
MYVAR=$(<command.in)
echo $MYVAR
$MYVAR

which gives:
bash simple.sh
ls $DIR
ls: cannot access '$DIR': No such file or directory

When you do $MYVAR, the variable gets expanded, once. So it produces ls $DIR and that is what is executed. With eval you can force another level of variable expansion:
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/tmp"
MYVAR=$(<command.in)
echo "$MYVAR"
eval "$MYVAR"


Perfect! using eval solved the problem. Thanks!
Most examples I saw about eval were something like eval $var which I don't know the difference between that and  just calling $var directly.

You still need to quote variable echo "$MYVAR" and eval "$MYVAR"

need is a bit exaggerated; it works without quoting. But I agree: quoting should have been done.

@LjmDullaart, ...it "works" without quoting. As in, it looks like it works until you try an interesting case, and then it fails in surprising ways.

As an example, compare eval "$code" and eval $code with code=$'printf \' * %s\\n\' *'. And the latter of course is much worse than just bad output if you have a file with $(rm -rf ~) as part of its name in the current working directory when run.

Just change command.in to
ls "$1"

then execute it like an ordinary script (since it now is an ordinary, parameterized script).
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/tmp"

bash command.in "$DIR"

